# Why unzip does not stop inside Docker image

Tags: linux, macos, docker, dockerfile, unzip

I am trying to `unzip` a ZIP file (>2 GB) as a part of a `Dockerfile`. This ZIP file contains a single CSV file (>25 GB). When I try to `unzip` it directly on my machine (MacOS 10.15.4, MacBook Pro 16-inch) it works fine, I also ran the command inside the Docker instance and it worked fine. The disk image size limit is set to 60 GB, each time I try to build the image the `unzip` command is running untill the disk image size limit is reached. I also checked whether the ZIP file is corrupted, and `unzip -t` did not show any error. I am not doing anything "extra" inside the `Dockerfile`, just trying to download and unzip the file.

```
# I also checked the alpine base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN curl -LO http://something.com/file.zip
RUN unzip file.zip
```

Does somebody know what is going on?

Comment: If you're running Docker on MacOS, then Docker is actually running in a Linux virtual machine. It's possible that the VM doesn't have enough space on the filesystem. [These docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/space/) have some information that might be useful.

Comment: unzip is trying to unzip the directory in `/` folder, cause it unzips the files in current directory by default. I assume you've full access to it. Check if it is permission related error. Post the full output of your `docker build`.

Comment: You will run into a bunch of practical issues with this image; if nothing else, you'll have to transfer the full 2 GB over a socket connection every time you do a `docker build`, and `docker push` and `pull` will have to copy the 25 GB unzipped file; I've had a lot of trouble with single layers starting around 1 GB.  You might push in the data file using something like a bind mount instead of baking it into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right, I was so focused on fixing the `Dockerfile` that I did not realize I would have such a big image at the end. Thank you!